# Help with a differential equations problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm new to stackexchange.
I had a quick question about a second order linear equation.
I need to find a differential equation $x(t)$ that solves the given equation.
$x''=x'^2(tanh)x$

I know that I have to substitute in $v(dv/dx)$ in for $x''$ and v in for $x'$.
Here's my question. I have never encountered tanh nor learned about it in our class. Is $tan(h)$ a function? Is h a constant? Is this a some well known variable?
Thanks!

Comment: "tanh" most likely refers to the [hyperbolic tangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions). On the other hand, if it actually means $\tan(h)$, I would say it is a rather confusing choice for a variable name.

Comment: Welcome to the site, by the way. If you wish, you can check out [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how math can be formatted on this site.

Comment: You should spell $\tanh(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a first order equation for $x'.$  we have $$\frac{dx'}{x'^2} = \frac{\sinh x \, dx}{\cosh x}$$ which integrates to $$-\frac{1}{x'} = \cosh x - C $$ now we can solve $$t = \int(C-\cosh x)\, dx = Cx -\sinh x + D$$